# Some rows not showing while they are in the page and its source code

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with css but I'm not abble to solve it. I have 20 results that should display in my web site, but it only displays 14 of them.. the other ones I can see them in the source code if I select the inspector.
I can move the position of the menu up or down and I can see the other elements are kind of hiding, but only moving down or up I can see them while I'm not able to increase the size of the space showing the rows.

here is a screenshot of my issue, twenty results should be there:[image]

here is my html-php code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>


        <title>Offers | <?php echo SITE_NAME; ?> example</title>





        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryCustom.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/commons.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/helpers.css">
        <style type="text/css">
        .biggerfont {   font-size: 14px;
}
        </style>


        </head><body  class="tgz" >

            <?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
         <?php include('includes/sub_menu.php'); ?>
        <div id="app_content">
          <div class="container">

            <style>
#ajaxLoadingModalBox{
    display:none;
}
#ajaxLoadingModalBox_container{
    background-color: inherit;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 2000; 
    background-color: inherit; 
    padding: 0px;
    width: 72px; 
    height: 72px; 
    left: 46%; 
    top: 46%;
}
.rf-pp-shade {
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#project_selector [isDisabled = 'true']{
    color : grey;
}
            </style>
            <div id="error_messages"></div>
            <div class="page-content">   <div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="script-tabs"> 
              <div id="projects_container" class="clearfix">
                <div class="clearfix" style="display: table;">
                  <div id="menu_left" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">
                    <div id="project_creator"> <a id="create-new-item" href="create_offer.html">Create new Offer</a></div>
                    <div id="project_selector">
                      <form action="offers.html" method="get">
                        <input placeholder="Search" id="projects_list_search" type="text" name="search" value="<?=$search;?>"/>
                      </form>
                      <div id="projects_list">
                        <div style="height: 354px;" class="scrollbar disable">
                          <div style="height: 354px;" class="track">
                            <div style="top: 0px; height: 354px;" class="thumb">
                              <div class="end"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 100%;" class="viewport">
                          <div style="top: -1px;" class="overview">
                            <ul>
                                                           <li class="projects-list-item selected" isdisabled="false" data-id="0f53ee7c-f894-42dd-b2f7-ddf576a04db1"> <span class="left">My Offers</span> <span class="right"> </span></li>
                              <?php if ($frow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                             do {
                                  $rows = 0;
                             ?>
                               <a href="view_offer.html?id=<?=$frow["softwares_id"];?>">  <li class="projects-list-item"> <span class="left">   <?=ucwords($frow["software_name"]);?></span></li></a>
                              <?php
                             $rows++;
                                 } while (($frow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($rows < $recordsPerPage));
                               } 
                               if($noRecords==0){
                               ?>
                              <li class="projects-list-item" isdisabled="true" data-id="0f53ee7c-f894-42dd-b2f7-ddf576a04db1"> <span class="left">No records found.</span> <span class="right"> </span></li>
                              <?php }?>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="project_details" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;">

                    <h1><strong>Create Your Offer </strong></h1>
                    <p><br>
                    </p>
                    <p>Advertising through <?php echo SITE_NAME; ?> is ideal for software companies and developers looking to promote many types of apps including: <br>
                    Tool bars, Search engines,Browsers, Browser extensions, Desktop widgets, AV software, Coupon and shopping alert <br>
                    systems and many others.</p>
                    <p><br>
                    </p>
                    <table width="767" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="115"><img src="img/SDK_BOX_16.jpg"></td>
                          <td width="617"><ul>
                            <li>Reach millions of new users from the far corners of the Internet who choose to install your app</li>
                            <li></li>
                          </ul></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="767">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="114"><img src="img/SDK_BOX_15.jpg"></td>
                          <td width="618"><ul>
                            <li>Cost-effective software pay per install distribution, Reach the largest possible audience</li>
                            <li></li>
                          </ul></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table width="767" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="114"><img src="img/SDK_BOX_13.jpg"></td>
                          <td width="618"><ul>
                            <li>Built-in A/B testing and analytics to track and optimize performance.</li>
                          </ul></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <table width="767" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="114"><img src="img/SDK_BOX_14.jpg"></td>
                          <td width="618"><p><br>
                          </p>
                            <ul>
                              <li>Strongest anti fraud system to ensure you are only paying for installations by real users</li>
                            </ul></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>   </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" id="ajaxLoadingModalBox">
              <div style="z-index:2000;" id="ajaxLoadingModalBox_shade" class="rf-pp-shade">
                <button id="ajaxLoadingModalBoxFirstHref" class="rf-pp-btn" tabindex="-1"> </button>
              </div>
              <div id="ajaxLoadingModalBox_container" class="rf-pp-cntr ">
                <div id="ajaxLoadingModalBox_shadow" class="rf-pp-shdw" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 72px; left: 5px; top: 5px; bottom: -5px;"></div>
                <div id="ajaxLoadingModalBox_content_scroller" class="rf-pp-cnt-scrlr" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;">
                  <div style="background-color: inherit;padding:0px;" id="ajaxLoadingModalBox_content" class="rf-pp-cnt">
                    <div style="padding:20px"> <img style="width:32px; height:32px;" src="img/page-spinner.gif"> </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this is some css code:

```
/* --------------------------- common.css ------------------------------------- */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-light-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .printable,
    .printable * {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .printable {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}

html, body, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset,  label, img, input,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* firefox line-height fix */
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {

    background-color: #474141;
    color: #469965;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.header-green-line {
    height: 5px;
    background: #609e79;
}

h1 { 
    font-size: 22px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #003333
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

a,
input {
    outline: medium none;
}

label {
    display: inline;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 14px;
}

a,
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:hover {
    color: #95c8aa ;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.list-inline > li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1240px;
}


.container:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#project_tab,
#app_console_tab,
#plugin_tab {
    padding: 40px;
    padding-right: 35px !important;
    border: none;
}

.extend-full,
.extend-left {
    padding-left: 3000px;
    margin-left: -3000px;
}

.extend-full,
.extend-right {
    padding-right: 3000px;
    margin-right: -3000px;
}

#warning_banner {
    background: #AD2535;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#app_content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#app_approval {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 115px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 1755px;
    top: 329px;
}
.tiggzi_btn, input.tiggzi_btn, button.tiggzi_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}





    /* Projects page */

    #projects_sidebar {
        float: left;
    }

    /* Projects list */

    #projects_list_search {
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 7px 25px 7px 15px;
        background: white url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat 98% 50%;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 270px;
    }

    #projects_list_search::-ms-clear {
        display: none;
    }

    .projects-list-item,
    .databases-list-item,
    .collections-list-item {
        padding:  3px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #FFF;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }

    .projects-list-item span.left,
    .databases-list-item span.left,
    .collections-list-item span.left{
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 45px;
    }

    .projects-list-item:hover span.left,
    .databases-list-item:hover span.left,
    .collections-list-item:hover span.left {
        width: 79%;
    }

    .projects-list-item span.right,
    .databases-list-item span.right,
    .collections-list-item span.right{
        padding-top: 13px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .projects-list-item.selected,
    .databases-list-item.selected,
    .collections-list-item.selected {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .projects-list-item.selected:hover,
    .databases-list-item.selected:hover,
    .collections-list-item.selected:hover {
        /*color: black;*/
    }

    .system-collection-selector, .custom-collection-selector {
        margin: 0 20px;
    }

    .system-collection-selector .collections-list-item.selected:hover {
        color: black; /* Don't highlight system collection name on mouse hover */
    }

    .projects-list-item:active,
    .databases-list-item:active,
    .collections-list-item:active {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
    }

    .projects-list-item button,
    .databases-list-item button,
    .collections-list-item button,
    .libs-table button,
    .scripts-table button {
        display: none;
    }

    .projects-list-item:last-child,
    .databases-list-item:last-child,
    .collections-list-item:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .collections-list-item:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .projects-list-item:hover,
    .databases-list-item:hover,
    .collections-list-item:hover,
    .scripts-table tr:hover,
    .libs-table tr:hover {
        color: #95c8aa ;
        background-color: #507f63;
    }

    .projects-list-item:hover button,
    .databases-list-item:hover button,
    .collections-list-item:hover button,
    .libs-table tr:hover button,
    .scripts-table tr:hover button {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }


    .projects-list-item img,
    .databases-list-item img,
    .collections-list-item img{
      padding-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    #users-collection-item span:before {
        display: inline-block;
        content: " ";
        width: 23px;
        height: 14px;
        background: url("../img/users_collection_icon.png") no-repeat left center;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    .selected#users-collection-item span:before {
        background-position: 0 -14px;
    }

    #files-collection-item span:before {
        display: inline-block;
        content: " ";
        width: 14px;
        height: 17px;
        background: url("../img/files_collection_icon.png") no-repeat left center;
        margin-left: 4px;
        margin-right: 14px;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    .selected#files-collection-item span:before {
        background-position: 0 -17px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the clearfix class has overflow: hidden; but I don't know if that's in the supplied css. Press F12 on your browser to open developer tools then use the element selector to get the containing div for the projects list. You will then be able to see which styles are applied based on the classes. Then you'll know what needs changing.